# Pass generic template class as functor parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, iterator, corba

I want to improve the following code snippet:

```
THNNetIPInfoIter last = std::unique(fist, end, HNInfoIPComparator());
```

where currently `HNInfoIPComparator()` is implemented as following:

```
// equal comparator
class HNInfoIPComparator
{
    public:
      bool operator()(const THNNetIPInfo &a, const THNNetIPInfo &b);
      bool operator()(const SDK::TIPAddressDescription &a, const SDK::TIPAddressDescription &b);
      bool operator()(const THNNetIPInfo &a, const SDK::TIPAddressDescription &b);
      bool operator()(const SDK::TIPAddressDescription &a, const THNNetIPInfo &b);
};
```

The reason for this comparator definition is that it might be used with another STL algorithms, like `std::set_difference` and should handle case when ranges has different types.

The problem is that I have to write huge amount of very similar comparators and it is easy to be entangled with which comparator to use.

I want to write the following snippet:

```
template<typename SDKClass, typename IDLClass>
class equal {
public:
  bool operator()(const IDLClass &a, const IDLClass &b) {
      if (strcmp(a.ipaddr.in(), b.ipaddr.in())) {
          return false;
      }
      return true;
  }

  bool operator()(const SDKClass &a, const SDKClass &b) {
      if (strcmp(a.ip_address().c_str(), b.ip_address().c_str())) {
          return false;
      }
      return true;
  }

  bool operator()(const IDLClass &a, const SDKClass &b) {
      if (strcmp(a.ipaddr.in(), b.ip_address().c_str())) {
          return false;
      }
      return true;
  }

  bool operator()(const SDKClass &a, const IDLClass &b) {
      if (strcmp(a.ip_address().c_str(), b.ipaddr.in())) {
          return false;
      }
      return true;
  }
};
```

So `HNInfoIPComparator()` would be generated depending on types passed as its arguments inside `std::unique` function.

*Therefore I want to pass to `std::unique` templated functor (class). Is it possible to do that and how?*

*Also I want to handle case when functor contains some internal data, which are used for comparisons*

Most important code samples:

```
// Automatically generated structure from IDL specification
// Basically simple structure
struct  THNNetIPInfo
{     
    typedef THNNetIPInfo_var _var_type;
    typedef THNNetIPInfo_out _out_type;

    static void _tao_any_destructor (void *);
    ::TAO::String_Manager ipaddr;
    ::TAO::String_Manager netmask;
};

// THNNetIPInfoIter - class external iterator
// which was written manually
typedef Util::CorbaSeqIter<THNNetIPInfoList, THNNetIPInfo> THNNetIPInfoIter;

// THNNetIPInfoList - also automatically generated class
// from IDL specification, list of THNNetIPInfo elements
THNNetIPInfoList list(...);
THNNetIPInfoIter first(&list, 0);
THNNetIPInfoIter end(&list, list.length());
```

Comment: Would it be feasible to create a `HNInfoIP` type that is implicitly convertible from both `THNNetIPInfo` and `TIPAddressDescription`? This would cut the operator overloads on `HNInfoIPComparator` to one.

Comment: Have you looked at the IDL to C++11 language mapping for CORBA, that mapping is way easier to use, will simplify the implementation of your comparator function greatly.

Comment: Yes,, I know about new CORBA versions which maps to C++11. But, unfortunately, I couldn't find any free substitution of old TAO Corba. Do you know any? I found only TAOX11, but it needs pay.

Comment: TAOX11 is at this moment the only implementation as far as I know, it is a commercial product with developer licenses, not free as TAO.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing a class template with four comparison operators, write a plain class with a templated comparison operator that adapts the inputs into the keys you want to compare:

```
class HNInfoIPComparator {
    static const char* adapt(const THNNetIPInfo& t) {
        return t.ipaddr.in();
    }

    static const char* adapt(const SDK::TIPAddressDescription& t) {
        return t.ip_address().c_str();
    }

public:
    template <typename T, typename U>
    bool operator()(const T& t, const U& u) const {
        return !strcmp(adapt(t), adapt(u));
    }
};
```

You can extend the comparator easily by adding overloads of `adapt` for additional types, e.g., `std::string` or `const char*`.

Comment: But this approach also requires generating multiple comparators, when I need same `operator()` but on another class member. Fox example I have to write `HNNetMaskComparator` with same types for `adapt`, but inside `return t.netmask.in()`, or `HNInfoInterface` with `return.interface.in()`. I want something more general, like `equal` which for this call `equal(THNNetIPInfo, netmask)` will generate correct operator `return !strcmp(t.netmask.in(), u.netmask.in())` automatically.